# C function to transpose matrix does not update matrix

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently building a matrix calculator (required to make with pointers) as part of my introductory C assignment, and I am currently trying to make an option to Transpose a 3x3 matrix (swapping the rows of a matrix with it's columns).

However, when I apply the function on the matrix nothing happens to it.

Here is the code for the transposition function.

```
void transposeMatrix(int matrix[3][3]) {

    int row;
    int col;

    int temp = 0;
    for (row = 0; row<3; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            temp = *(*(matrix+row)+col);
            *(*(matrix+row)+col) = *(*(matrix+col)+row);
            *(*(matrix+col)+row) = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

It is just a standard swapping algorithm with a temp variable.

Here is the code for the printing function

```
void printMatrix(char *desc,int matrix[3][3]) {

    int row;
    int column;

    printf("matriks %s:\n",desc);
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
            printf(" %d", matrix[row][column]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

And here is how I call the function:

```
int sampleM1[3][3] = {{2,2,4}, {1,1,1}, {1,1,1}};

printMatrix("before transposition", sampleM1);
transposeMatrix(sampleM1);
printMatrix("after transposition" , sampleM1);
```

The output of the entire operation is that sampleM1 does not change at all. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: @TomKarzes Yea, I do agree that using regular array syntax makes it far clearer, however my instructor required me to use pointers in the assignment. Also, I did use a temp variable in my code.

Comment: Oops, yeah you did, sorry, the explicit pointer expressions were so distracting I didn't even see it when I first glanced at it.

Comment: Ok, here's what the problem is:  You're iterating over all rows, and for each row you're iterating over all columns.  So for instance, you will visit both (1, 2) and (2, 1).  When you visit (1, 2), you swap those two entries.  But when you visit (2, 1), you swap them again, undoing the first swap.  You instead need to iterate over a trangular portion of the matrix, e.g. `for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)` and `for (col = 0; col < row; col++)`.  That way `col` will always be less than `row`, so you'll visit each distinct pair once rather than twice.  (When they're equal, no swap is needed.)

Comment: You could, of course, start the first loop at `1` rather than `0`, i.e. `for (row = 1; row < 3; row++)` and `for (col = 0; col < row; col++)`.  The point is you do a swap for (1, 0), (2, 0), and (2, 1).  This will swap those with (0, 1), (0, 2), and (1, 2).  The diagonal is unchanged of course.

Comment: The inner loop needs to start at `col = row + 1` for reasons given above.

Comment: @MadPhysicist My solution is simpler.  Why do you want to do the unnecessary addition?  Either will work, so might as well use the simpler one.

Comment: @TomKarzes. For a 3x3 array, I agree that you may as well hard code the indices.

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you for the solution! I ultimately ended up choosing another algorithm but at least I knew where I went wrong on my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TomKarzes noted above you visit the same index of the matrix twice, and avoid that by starting the inner loop at row + 1. You mentioned that you needed to use pointer syntax, which is fine of course, but `swap()` now localizes the ugliness (to arguments) for you to change as you see fit.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void printMatrix(int matrix[N][N]) {
    for (uint8_t row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (uint8_t col = 0; col < N; col++)
            printf("%d%s", matrix[row][col], col + 1 < N ? ", " : "\n");
}

void transposeMatrix(int matrix[N][N]) {
    for (uint8_t row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (uint8_t col = row + 1; col < N; col++)
            swap(&matrix[row][col], &matrix[col][row]);
}

int main() {
    int matrix[N][N] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    printMatrix(matrix);
    transposeMatrix(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Here is the output of the above:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
1, 4, 7
2, 5, 8
3, 6, 9
```